# How can I fix Grails error: "No domain class found for name PrivacyOptions. Please try again and enter a valid domain class name"

Tags: class, grails, dns

I'm just getting started with Groovy/Grails.

I added a new domain controller to my project, and generate-controller doesn't like it.

There are other indications something's wrong: If I run the app no table is actually created in the database for this.

I've reduced the DomainController to one String field and no constraints, just to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my specification. I also tried renaming it, just in case there was something about the original name (Privacy) that conflicted with something.

I'm sure I have the correct name, and that the file is called PrivacyOptions.groovy and inside the class is also called PrivacyOptions.

Here's the error:

```
Running script /opt/local/grails/scripts/GenerateController.groovy
Environment set to development
Domain class not found in grails-app/domain, trying hibernate mapped classes...
No domain class found for name PrivacyOptions. Please try again and enter a valid domain class name
```

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I needed to include the package name when calling 'grails generate-all packagename.domain'

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add the project name (aka the package name from the first line of the model file) before the model name.

```
grails generate-all projectname.Class
```

This is the one that finally worked for me, after an hour of head scratching and googling.

ref: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Generate-Scaffold-Scripts-Don-t-Work-Getting-No-domain-class-found-Error-td2017858.html#a2017880

> As of 1.2.2 Grails creates artifacts in packages that default to your
>   project name - see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5713
>   So you'd need to run `grails generate-all srapp.Srmodel`
>   - Burt

Comment: If you're in interactive mode, after typing `generate-all `, hit tab, and it should autofill with your package name and display possible classes to use. Saves some typing and remembering.

Comment: I can't quite get over how many people have tripped over this and upvoted it in the three years since I posted it. This was my first and last encounter with grails as I lost all faith in grails as a platform at this point. Many thanks all for the rep :-)

Comment: When a SO search didn't help, I did a Google search and this popped up. Saved me asking a duplicate question! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 10):

it's not projectname.Class , it must be dirname.classname .

eg: your projectname is Helloworld, the directory is "grails-app/domain/helloworld/User.groovy" . so , the command is "grails generate-all helloworld.User" ,but not "Helloworld.User"

Answer (score 8):

Run:

```
grails clean
```

and then re-run the `generate-all` command.

ref: http://parasjain.net/2009/06/23/grails-no-domain-class-found-for-name-please-try-again-and-enter-a-valid-domain-class-name/

Answer (score 3):

Great help. I faced the same problem following [this tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-grails01158/) that names the project as "trip-planner" and Grails generates the domain directories as '~/trip/planner/' instead of '~/trip-planner/'. Then the generate-all command for a Trip class should be 'grails generate-all trip.planner.Trip'

Just in case someone adds a '-' character to the project name.

Answer (score 1):

Yep... worked for me too. I just prefixed the package name to the class I was trying to generate-all for and it worked. So ...

**generate-all racetrack.User**

Bit of a pants bug really since all other grails commands do not require a package name to be included :-))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got to this point, but maybe [this](http://grails.org/Quick+Start) will help you get over the hump.

Am I correct to assume that you used "grails create-domain-class" to create PrivacyOptions domain object, and the Groovy script showed up in your grails-app/domain directory?  Did you get a PrivacyOptionsTests in test/unit?  Did that pass?  Did you add a package?

Comment: I did it from the NetBeans IDE. I tink the problem was that when I created the file I selected the option "create a groovy class" instead of the option "create a domain class".

I guess somewhere in some secret config file is a list of classes that are Domains and that the create-domain-class does the necessary housekeeping.

Comment: Yes, create-domain-class is the key.

Comment: The Groovy file simply has to be in the grails-app/domain folder. There is no secret config file

Comment: @Scott Warren - This is not correct. I have the domain in the grails-app/domain folder and am running into the same issue as a result of not using the create-domain-class

Comment: [Grails Docs.](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-domain-class.html) see near the bottom "Note that this command is merely for convenience and you can also create domain classes in your favourite text editor or IDE if you choose."

Answer (score 0):

related issue about stack trace not being clear for missing properties:

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1607

Answer (score 0):

generate-all Domainname will not work as the full package name is needed.
I tent to do add an * for the first time and then you will see what the domain class should look like for the other calls.

```
generate-all *
```

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-all.html

Answer (score 0):

It must be dirname.classname.

If you have a domain class created Book, like this 'grails-app/domain/book/Book.groovy'

The it should be: grails generate-app book.Book

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Groovy/Grails Tool Suite, you can simply see the domain name by right clicking on the controller that you created, notice the exact case for domain name, then right click on views and generate views and type in domainname.viewname

Example, your controller name is RegistrationController and domain name is helloworld, you can right click on views and in generate views dialog, enter the value as helloworld.Registration